# The meaning of a symbol in a paper

Tags: notation, operator-theory, math-history, adjoint-operators

I have some trouble figuring out  the meaning of this symbol $\upharpoonright$ in this paper.

I have never seen this.

[image]

The paper is "Inverse Scattering on the Line". Sorry for the author, my math is not good enough...

Comment: I read this as “restricted to”, i.e., the “same” operator is considered in all three cases, but acting only on the smooth functions with certain domain, an this is then Friedrich extended to the respective $L^2$ spaces.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help.